# Can access TextView but not LinearLayout declared in the same way

Tags: java, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout

I want to add a TextView to a LinearLayout in Java, but as soon as I access the LinearLayout `linlay_container` in `make_systematics()`, I get a NullPointerException. I have the exact same code for defining the LinearLayout and a TextView `textview_systematics` inside of the LinearLayout. I **can** access the TextView, but **not** the LinearLayout. What is wrong here?

This layout is a fragment and included with the `<fragment>`-Tag, just in case this could be important.

The xml file (fragment_species_systematics.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id              = "@+id/linlay_fragment_species_systematics"
    android:layout_width    = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation     = "vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id              = "@+id/textView_fragment_species_systematics"
        android:layout_width    = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height   = "wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Java file:

```
public class Fragment_Species_Systematics extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout    linlay_container;
    TextView        textview_systematics;
    View            view;

    public Fragment_Species_Systematics() {}



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_species_systematics, container, false);

    return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        linlay_container     = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linlay_fragment_species_systematics);
        textview_systematics = (TextView)     getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_fragment_species_systematics);
    }



    public void make_systematics(String json_systematics) {
        if (textview_systematics.isAttachedToWindow())  {Log.i("DEBUG", "tv is attached");} else {Log.i("DEBUG", "tv is not attached");}
        if (linlay_container.isAttachedToWindow())      {Log.i("DEBUG", "ll is attached");} else {Log.i("DEBUG", "ll is not attached");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, unfortunately without finding any reason **why** I have do the following: Apparently one can not access the "global" LinearLayout. I have to include another LinearLayout and access **that** one, then it works.

My working xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id                = "@+id/linlay_fragment_species_systematics"
        android:layout_width      = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height     = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation       = "vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id            = "@+id/textView_fragment_species_systematics"
            android:layout_width  = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```